# How to replace Production data with dummy text in Development Environment

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, office-365, development-enviroment

What is the best way to replace sensitive document contents with dummy text for development environment?

File Types:
.txt
.pdf
.xml

the requirement is to keep file permissions and replace the file with a template or dummy file. File names stay as they are.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such way option avaiabale which will do this thing. But I would do this way.

- Create a new site collection in Production farm
- apply all customization etc to that site colelction.
- Now upload the dummy documents on it.
- set the permission on that site collection.
- Now uplaod test documents often.
- Now when ever you want, you can backup the site collection and restore it in your dev.

Other Way is

- Backup production site in lower farm.
- delete all the confidential data
- Remove permissions and make the developer's admin on them.

Comment: I would like to keep actual files in their location with their permissions.

Comment: i am not saying delete actual files, What i am saying...take a backup of site collection and restore it to your dev /test farm then perform the deletion...this way it will not effect production

Comment: I mean I would like to keep the same files in Dev but not the actual content of them...